# Determining default privacy settings

Tags: privacy

I'm building a web-based app that will be used by social groups where people frequently need to interact with each other offline. The manager of a group uploads a list of group members, including their email and phone numbers, and only logged-in group members can see the pages for that group.

My question is, what should the default privacy setting be for the email and phone info? Should I make it visible to other group members by default, or hidden by default? A user can update their profile to change the settings.

In our beta groups, I have email and phone hidden by default. I find that most people don't bother checking their profile, even when specifically prompted to do so. So my group managers are complaining that members can't find other people's contact info because most of it is hidden. (Group managers can always see all information.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it should default to hidden.

Can your users send each other messages without revealing their email address or phone number? If so, use that opportunity to point out that other users can’t see their contact info whenever they are sent a message.

Comment: Thanks, Synchro. I don't have an internal messaging system within my app. My users are primarily senior citizens who have relied on paper directories with phone and emails, and we're trying to move that online. They can't see anything without being logged in, so I'm debating making available what they could previously see on paper.